# SQL Server 2016 installation - server details

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, database-installation

I am planning to use SQL Server 2016 for ODS (operational data store) setup. with OS cluster & DB cluster. Please suggest what the server configurations min and max & server OS details should be, which will be best suited for any load of data transformation. Majorly all ETL work. You can call it as ETL server.

We are planning to install in VM servers. Need complete details or prerequisites of the servers. I checked in MSDN, but details are in high level.

Comment: You might get more luck on Server Fault, as this is not a programming related question. You will also need to give more detail about the sort of data volumes you are expecting. Also note that 2016 has not been released yet, so HW requirements and performance characteristics may change

Comment: hi but in wiki it say's it is already released.

Comment: the data size is about 50GB to 1 TB